# enable_if for generic operator T()

Tags: c++, templates, g++, type-traits

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename X>
struct test
{
    operator int() const { puts("?"); return 0; }
    template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<X, void*>::value, T>::type>
    operator T() const { puts("T"); return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    test<void*> t;
    char* c = (char*)t;
    switch (t)
    {
        case 0: break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error that g++-4.7 gives

```
user@user:~$ g++-4.7 -std=c++0x test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:14: error: ambiguous default typeconversion from ‘test<void*>’
test.cpp:13:14: error:   candidate conversions include ‘template<class T, class> test::operator void*() const [with T = T; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; X = void*]’
```

g++ 4.6 compiles it without errors and different operators are actually called.

Is there a way to make this work under g++ 4.7?

UPDATE: actually it works in 4.6 without any enable_if at all... so the question still applies but I'm now not sure if enable_if will help.

Comment: You may directly specialize `test<void*>` instead of using `std::enable_if`...

Comment: `enable_if`'s second template parameter is defaulted. You don't need to use it.

Comment: Hm, in reality "test" is not a templated class and X type comes from a macro instead... I think simplifying code for SO changed things a bit. I may think of making a templated class instead but this will probably give too much trouble.

Comment: Why do you need templated conversion operator?

Comment: In real app "test" class emulates properties. I want to avoid changing thousands of places where this code compiles under Windows but not under Linux. Real-app class "test" has operator (for example) void* which is property type, but it is casted to e.g. Object*. Or it has operator EnumType, but it is casted to EnumType2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at least one "acceptable" solution:

```
#define switch(x) \
    switch( (typename switch_type<__typeof(x)>::type)(x) )
```

which switch_type trait can be extended to resolve ambiguity for specific app-related types (property types).

Answer (score 1):

If you add an explicit cast to `int` here:

`switch ((int)t)`

Then it should compile.

I think it's complaining about the conversion being ambiguous since there exists more than one type that can hold a `0` value.

I'm using g++ 4.8 though.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid with all these operators - changing 2000 switches in the code. So while this will work this is not the solution that I need.

Comment: I've got a funny feeling your ambition might be out of luck. I think there is a rule that says type casts need to be explicit for objects that define their own....but I might be wrong.